# Unexpected environment preparation error: failed to create runner binary: error during connect:

Tags: docker, circleci-2.0

Error:
Unexpected environment preparation error: failed to create runner binary: error during connect: Put http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.39/containers/e06b3801bd1b159c9227eebf7796d5007433dc58c4fc1c355758f5a9783b8e8f/archive?noOverwriteDirNonDir=true&path=%2Fbin: unexpected EOF

Step failed
Task failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow the steps, I hope issue will be solved. In my case it's working.

```
sudo service docker stop
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
sudo service docker start
```